# What is Windows Spotlight?

Tags: windows-spotlight

I'm familiar with MacOS spotlight OS feature which is to quickly search stuff on your hard drive including apps etc, but what does it mean in the context of the Windows OS? I don't think it's the same functionality unless I'm mistaking or missed something. What is the purpose of Spotlight in the Windows 10 OS?

[image: Windows Spotlight Background]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/windows-spotlight

> Windows Spotlight is an option for the lock screen background that displays different background images and occasionally offers suggestions on the lock screen.

> The Windows Spotlight displays a new image on the lock screen each day. The initial background image is included during installation. Additional images are downloaded on ongoing basis.

> The lock screen background will occasionally make recommendations on how to enhance your productivity and enjoyment of Microsoft products including suggesting other relevant Microsoft products and services.